# Creating Fake object to mock out GetHashCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

I have the following class (irrelevant portions removed)...

```
public class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    private readonly string m_nodeNameToCompare;

    public XElementComparer(string nodeNameToCompare)
    {
        m_nodeNameToCompare = nodeNameToCompare;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement element)
    {
        // Returns value of attribute.  Returns null if attribute does not exist.
        string value = element.GetNullableAttrText(m_nodeNameToCompare);
        return value == null ? element.GetHashCode() : value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test to test this method but `GetHashCode` returns a different value on every call, so I am trying to mock out `GetHashCode` using Microsoft Fakes (I am in VS 2012).

I can't figure out how to do this.  I have tried creating a Shim for XElement and a Stub for the object class but can't figure out how to bind the two together.  Am I trying to do something that is not possible or am I just missing something?

Here is my unit test code...

```
    // Arrange
    const int expected = 12345;
    const string nodeName = "guid";

    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Need to figure out how to mock out GetHashCode of the XElement class
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

        StubObject o = new StubObject();
        o.GetHashCode01 = () => expected;

        ShimXElement element = new ShimXElement();
        //element.Bind(o);

        // Act
        XElementComparer target = new XElementComparer(nodeName);
        int actual = target.GetHashCode(element);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I solved my problem but did not answer my original question so I am just adding my solution to the original question in case someone else has the solution.  I ended up solving the problem without mocking any objects.  It was one of those "duh" moments, instead of setting the expectation against a hard-coded value set it against the result of the `GetHashCode`.

```
// Arrange
const string nodeName = "guid";
XElement element = new XElement("Record");
int expected = element.GetHashCode();

// Act
XElementComparer target = new XElementComparer(nodeName);
int actual = target.GetHashCode(element);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

and then testing the other condition...

```
// Arrange
const string nodeName = "guid";
string attributeValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
XElement element = new XElement("Record", new XAttribute(nodeName, attributeValue));
int expected = attributeValue.GetHashCode();

// Act
XElementComparer target = new XElementComparer(nodeName);
int actual = target.GetHashCode(element);

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

It's not ideal because it does not mock out the GetNullableAttrText extension method but, IMHO, it is cleaner then using Fakes.

Comment: What is "o.GetHashCode01" - shouldn't it be "o.GetHashCode"

Comment: No.  The StubObject creates GetHashCode01 (of type Func<int>), which is a property which allows you to stub out the GetHashCode method.